# Restoring "remove ads" functionality when using consumable IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore, ads

I'm researching how to properly implement the functionality to remove ads in my app when the user makes any IAP and have that functionality restorable.

The way i'm seeing the first part done is to simply put a value in the user defaults that the user has made a purchase and check it before displaying ad. No problem.

But i don't know how to do the restorable part because all my products are consumables. How can I restore this value when the user reinstalls the app? Because as i understand the only record of a consumable is on the device and cannot be restored by apple correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: huh, removeAd usually is non-consumable. Once bought will last forever. Your consumable means that the removeAd will be expired in time? Or like removeAd for 10 pop up ads?

Comment: I think in this case removing ads is a "bonus" for purchasing any consumable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this purely through store-kit APIs, as there is no restorable purchase record as you say.  I can see a couple of options -

1. You could enable iCloud for your app and persist data to the user's iCloud account, however this won't work for users who don't have iCloud.
2. You could have the users register an account on your server and use that to store their purchase history (or provide a Facebook login etc).
3. If a user deletes and re-installs your app then they need to make another in-app purchase to remove the ads - Profit!

Comment: I think i'll try out the iCloud method, and have number 3 for the unfortunate users who don't use iCloud. Thanks!

Comment: The third option you provided violates [section 3.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase) of App Store Review Guidelines, I got my app rejected partly because of this. "Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may not expire, **and you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases.**"

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since consumable in app purchases are not restorable. I agree it is desirable that you provide some sort of account system to make it possible to restore consumables, but Storekit can't do this for you. Note that in this question, ad removal was a "side effect"of making any consumable in-App purchase. An explicit "remove ads" IAP would be considered a non-consumable IAP and would need to be restorable.